# Missing user accounts

Tags: discussion, deleted-users

Are there more deleted user accounts than the number of registered accounts minus the highest user account ID?

A highest current user account:

user: 10,317,846

When getting Stack Overflow metrics, it shows,
https://sostats.github.io/

10,697,950 total users..

That's a difference of almost 400,000...

Where did the missing users go to?

Comment: They're in a better place now

Comment: so..that makes about 1,000,000 deleted accounts... It doesnt add up to _Are there more deleted user accounts than the number of registered accounts_

Comment: edited: difference between user account values :)

Comment: @ivarni: there is a better place for programmers??

Comment: Any number of reasons: some choose to quit for whatever reasons. Some choose to make an account for a one off question.. other reasons: spammer/troll accounts deleted by SO

Comment: The id column of the users table is an MSSQL identity column. It doesn't guarantee that numbers are assigned consecutively.

Comment: Then what are the sequential gaps in the database based on?

Comment: On what ever SQL Server dreams up. See my answer on the id's for review id's: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291853/158100

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow used to automatically delete inactive accounts.

Comment: @Glorfindel Are you sure? I don't think SO automatically delete inactive accounts.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson they used to do but somewhere in 2017 they stopped running that batch.

Comment: And deleted are burninated secondary sockpuppet accounts!?

Comment: @ivarni Better place?

Comment: I would assume the only "better place" that a programmer would be is Hell..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As can be seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48263/295232), Stack Overflow used to delete up to 1000 inactive accounts *per day* since at least 2009. In the beginning, that number wasn't reached, but when it did, in less than three years, this adds up to 1,000,000 deleted users. This practice stopped in 2017.

I expect that the number of self-deleted accounts and users which were removed for reasons of spamming, sockpuppetry and/or trolling (mentioned by others in the comments) are much lower, but we'll probably need a ♦ moderator to confirm. As a baseline figure, the Charcoal project has detected 'only' [2,214 spammers](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/sites/dash?site_id=1&tab=spammers) on Stack Overflow since August 2015. We definitely missed some and not all of those accounts are deleted, but it puts the 1 million number in perspective.

Comment: Is there any reason why SO stop it in 2017. I searched, but could not find a meta discussion about that decision.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson IIRC the batch had *issues*. It was notoriously slow due to all kind of checks it had to do (you don't want to delete Jon Skeet's account by accident). For that reason it limited itself to a number of accounts to check that it could handle within a timeframe. That did lead to an ever growing backlog of accounts to be purged. The value of deleting those accounts is virtually zero so it was decided the batch didn't need to run anymore.

Comment: @rene I have noticed that you know lot of information about SO and your are really active on SO.But according your profile your are not a moderator or employee at SO..... So how do you know all these information? However, your are doing a great job here

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson I hang around in the wrong chatrooms, read  the wrong MSE posts and follow the wrong people on twitter. And if you have no life you end up with a lot of "knowledge" to impress people. Keep in mind I paraphrase bits and pieces and combine that with some logical reasoning. Only SE staff can confirm if I'm correct and you should only believe what they bring forward. I'm just passing by.